# How to write equivalent Tensorflow code with same logic?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,18])
```

I want to write a program that match each element of “myx” to “myy” using a greedy algorithm. The match will be 1:1, with caliper distance <=0.5, without replacement.
The algorithm is simple:

```
import numpy as np

myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,1.4])

Xxx=np.transpose(np.repeat(myx[:, np.newaxis], myy.size , axis=1))
Yyy=np.repeat(myy[:, np.newaxis], myx.size , axis=1)
# define a caliper 
calp=0.5

matches = {}
dist = np.abs(Xxx-Yyy)
print('Before loop distance matrix',dist)
for m in range(0, myx.size):
    if (np.nanmin(dist[:,m]) <= calp) or not calp:
        matches[m] = np.nanargmin(dist[:,m])  
        dist[matches[m],:]=None
print('Match Pairs:',matches)
print('After loop distance matrix',dist)
```

The problem is I don’t want to use anything in “np” or “panda”, but want to use Tensorflow framework only.  I have written part of the program, but find out it’s hard than I originally thoughts. Can someone help me?  By the way, this is the first time I try to use tensorflow..

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


#myx = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=3.5, size=(5000,))
#myy=np.random.uniform(low=0.8, high=5.0, size=(50000,))

myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,18])


Xxx=np.transpose(np.repeat(myx[:, np.newaxis], myy.size , axis=1))
Yyy=np.repeat(myy[:, np.newaxis], myx.size , axis=1)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(myy.size,myx.size))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(myy.size,myx.size))
# define a caliper 
calp=tf.constant(0.5,tf.float64)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    dist = tf.abs(tf.subtract(X,Y))

    # Use an explicit shape for `i`.
    i = tf.placeholder(dtype='int64', shape=[])

    # Add a second unused argument to `condition()`.
    def condition(i, *arg):
        return i <= myx.size-1
    # Add a second unused argument to `b()`.
    def b(i, temp, _):

        tfslic = dist[0:myy.size, i]

        # Drop the `axis` argument from `tf.reduce_min()`
        minVal=tf.reduce_min(tfslic)

        y = tf.cond(
            tf.less_equal(minVal, calp),
            # Reshape the output of `tf.argmin()` to be a scalar.
            lambda: tf.argmin(tfslic, 0),
            # Explicitly convert the false-branch value to `tf.int64`.
            lambda: tf.constant(99999, dtype=tf.int64))
    '''
    :::::::::::::PROBLEM START HERE:::::::::::
    For each tf.while_loop, with index "i"
    if the minimum value of distance matrix dist[,i] <= caliper
    then output the first min value index occurs i.e. (y,i)

    Then set dist[y,]=[None, None, None, None]   

    Given the example matix "myx","myy";
    The while loop should output match pair indx [[0,None],[1,5],[2,4],[3,None]]
    '''
        varDist=tf.Variable(dist)

        temp = tf.cond(
            tf.less_equal(minVal, calp),
            # Set dist matrix row y to [None, None, None, None].
            lambda: tf.assign(varDist[y,],[9999.,9999.,9999.,9999.]),
            # Do nothing.
            lambda: tf.Variable(dist))


        return i+1, y, temp

    # Add a dummy initial value for the second loop variable.
    # Rename the first return value to `i_out` to avoid clashing with `i` above.
    i_out, r, dist= tf.while_loop(condition, b, [i, dist, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64)])


sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
dmat = sess.run(dist, feed_dict={X:Xxx, Y: Yyy,i:0})
sess.close()

print(dmat)
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I edited the code, to show where are the problems

Comment: You should fix your target code, because it doesn't work right now. Is it `np.abs` there? How's `matches` defined?

Comment: @Maxim.  Sorry, pasted my original code (target code) using np only.

Answer (score 0):

Let me reformulate the question to see if I correctly understood. The problem is to, for each element `x` in `myx`, find the element in `myy` which is the closest to `x`, and match them if the distance is less than a caliper.

The results of matching can also be expressed as a list (of the same length as `myx`), each element in this list is the index in `myy` or `-1` if the smallest distance is larger than the caliper.

If you agree with the reformulation above, then there is an equivalent way to solve the problem, as presented in the function `npstyle()`, which can be translated to `tf_style()` very easily.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def npstyle_0():

    myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
    myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,1.4])

    Xxx = np.transpose(np.repeat(myx[:, np.newaxis], myy.size, axis=1))
    Yyy = np.repeat(myy[:, np.newaxis], myx.size, axis=1)
    # define a caliper
    calp = 0.5

    matches = {}
    dist = np.abs(Xxx - Yyy)
    print('Before loop distance matrix', dist)
    for m in range(0, myx.size):
        if (np.nanmin(dist[:, m]) <= calp) or not calp:
            matches[m] = np.nanargmin(dist[:, m])
            dist[matches[m], :] = None
    print('Match Pairs:', matches)
    print('After loop distance matrix', dist)


def npstyle():
    myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
    myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,1.4])
    # myx=np.array([3.0, 0.2, 4.0])
    # myy=np.array([10.1, 3.2, 0.1, 7.5])

    Xxx=np.transpose(np.repeat(myx[:, np.newaxis], myy.size, axis=1))
    Yyy=np.repeat(myy[:, np.newaxis], myx.size , axis=1)

    # define a caliper
    calp=0.5
    dist = np.abs(Xxx-Yyy)
    argmin = np.nanargmin(dist, 0)
    print('Before loop distance matrix', dist)
    match_dist = dist[argmin, np.arange(myx.size)]
    match_bool = match_dist <= calp
    matches = np.where(match_bool, np.nanargmin(dist, 0), -1)

    print matches
    print 'end np style.'


def tf_style():
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None,))  # setting (None,) allows to give an array of any length.
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None,))
    shape_x, shape_y = tf.shape(X)[0], tf.shape(Y)[0]
    Xxx = tf.reshape(tf.tile(X, [shape_y]), (shape_y, shape_x))
    Yyy = tf.reshape(tf.tile(Y, [shape_x]), (shape_x, shape_y))

    calp = 0.5
    dist = tf.abs(Xxx - tf.transpose(Yyy))
    argmin = tf.argmin(dist, axis=0, output_type=tf.int32)

    match_dist = tf.diag_part(tf.gather(dist, argmin))
    match_bool = tf.less_equal(match_dist, calp)
    matches = tf.where(match_bool, argmin, tf.fill([shape_x], -1))

    # ========= session of tensorflow ===========
    # gpu config
    # gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=False)
    # config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False, gpu_options=gpu_options)
    # sess = tf.Session(config)

    sess = tf.Session()

    feed_dict = {X: [2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6], Y: [10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,1.4]}
    [a, b, d, e] = sess.run([Xxx, Yyy, dist, matches],
                   feed_dict=feed_dict)

    print a
    print b
    print d
    print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # npstyle_0()
    npstyle()
    tf_style()
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your   `tf_style()`. But there is only one things you are missing is without replacement. Which means, (i.e.) after you match `X[1`] to `Y[5]`, `Y[5]` will be removed from `Y`, so that `X[2:3]` will not pick `Y[5]`, but index will still continue. In this example match`X` to `Y` in your  `tf_style()` will results     `[-1  5  4  7]`.

Comment: @user3491987 oops... then I have no idea how to do in tensorflow. How about `tf.py_func()`?